# An exploding projectile

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, projectile

> A mass $3m$ is thrown with a velocity of $20\sqrt3$ m/s at an angle of $30^{\circ}$ to the horizontal from a point, say $A$, on level ground. After reaching a certain height, $h$, it explodes into two fragments, $m$ and $2m$. Both fragments reach the ground at the same time, with the fragment of mass $m$ reaching $A$ with a velocity of $20$ m/s. Assume that there is no air drag and $g =10\ m/s^2$.

I think that we need to somehow find the angle at which mass $m$ strikes the ground, as then we will have the vertical velocity. But I can't decide whether the angle should be $30^{\circ}$ or not; how should I proceed?

Comment: Hi Aaratrick and welcome to the Physics SE! Please note that we don't answer homework or worked example type questions. Please see [this page in the site help](https://physics.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) for more on what topics you can ask about here.

Comment: You know the vertical velocity of each section when they hit the ground. Since they hit the ground at the same time then you know the explosion didn't affect the vertical velocities.

Comment: @JohnRennie I didn't mean to ask the question as a homework exercise; my main problem, which I mentioned as well, was that whether we can take the angle at which $m$ strikes the ground as $30^{\circ}$. I apologise, if I have broken the rules of this site.

Comment: @AaronStevens Could you please explain it a bit more? I don't understand how we can obtain the vertical velocities of both fragments.

Comment: Since they hit at the same time, the vertical velocities didn't change due to the explosion (if they did change then the two pieces start at height $h$ with different vertical velocities, therefore they would hit the ground at different times). Therefore, the vertical velocity of the sections moves just like as if there was no explosion. Hence each section hits the ground with the same vertical velocity magnitude as the initial projectile

Comment: @Aaratrick I would suggest making it clear that the angle is what you are asking about. If this is all you want to know then you don't need to give your attempt, all of that work, and don't say things like "I will appreciate any help or hints." Keep the question, then ask about the angle. Tell us why you think it should or shouldn't be $30^\circ$. Right now this question reads as a "help me with my homework" question

Comment: So due to my answer was deleted as "nearly complete answer", a fact I don't agree with, maybe more sketchy answer:
As we already mentioned the velocity in y don't change, because if they would, they impossibly could hit the ground at the same time. So you have to find two equations, containing $v_x$ after explosion and $t_s$, the time when they split. So you find $v_x$ and can calculate the angle, you're looking for (and check, that it doesn't definitely has to be the same angle, as the bis mass gets thrown away)

Comment: @pcalc It could be the same angle though :)

Comment: @AaronStevens of course it could - but is doesn't have to - this was what i meant :)

Comment: @AaronStevens Thanks for explaining and also for remarking on the question; I'll edit the question accordingly. I only mentioned the rest of the question and my attempt for context.

Comment: @pcalc I don't know why your answer was deleted, but thanks for explaining.

Comment: You should say why you think the angle is or is not $30^\circ$. pcalc's answer was deleted since it was pretty much a complete solution. It just left out the final calculation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no reason that the angle has to be $30^\circ$. If the body in question was the same, then yes it would have to be due to the conservation of momentum. However, the body, and thus momentum, will be split after the explosion. So, it does not need to be the same angle as the start.

Create general equations of motion till before they explode.
Since time to fall is equal, the $y$-component of velocity has to be same as this is the only determinant of time. Use conservation of momentum to find equations for the new projectiles. You will need one for $v_x$ to do trig for the angle. Remember that the $x$ distance back is the same as at point $h$.

Use these equations and then work backwards by equating to the given speed, $20\space  m/s$. As you know should know $v_y$ and $v_x$, using $\arcsin$ you can find the angle you're asking about. Is it going to be $30^\circ$? Maybe not...

Note: You did not mention what the problem wants solved, so I've focused on the angle you asked about.

Comment: I tried doing a proof by contradiction on this by showing that if the angle is $30^\circ$ then the explosion must have happened right at the peak of the trajectory. But I think that's actually what happens here, so no contradiction was arrived at.